# Removing the 'spaces' occupied by "display:none"d elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I searched and saw that this question was asked numerous times, but I can't seem to find a solution working for my current layout.

I have this

html:

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="button" id="buttonHello" class="hiddenButton">
            <b id="textHello">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="button" id="buttonBye" class="hiddenButton">
            <b id="textBye">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hiddenButton{
    display:none;
}
```

and in my js when I do things like this,

```
if (something) document.getElementById('buttonBye').style.display='inline';
```

I still got the space occupied by the non displayed button and text. I tried different solutions, but none that were consistant.

Thanks!

edit: Yes it's a mockup, I don't have access to the real code at this moment.

Comment: Can you show the real HTML What you have here is a mockup. Or if it contains sensitive info, at least show something that actually works. For instance, make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Are you saying that elements with `diplay: none` are using up space in the layout? Because that's really not a likely cause of your problem; browsers don't do that.

Comment: you are having this problem most likely because you are using tables and the td or tr element has a fixed width already.

Comment: display: none removes the element completely from the document, it doesn't take up any space.

Comment: why don't you use jquery instead ..

Answer (score 2):

By default, table cells have padding, and tables have cellspacing to make it nice and organised.

In order to completely hide these, you would need to actually toggle the `display` of the `<tr>` elements, NOT their contents.

Comment: For tables, it's best not to mess with their `display` property; using the `visibility` property is better.

Comment: @Kolink No, for tables there's a special value `visibility:collapse` that does the same as `display:none`, except it keeps the structural integrity of the table intact. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility

Comment: Ooh, interesting. I had no idea about that XD

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser, tables have a default value (non-zero) value for cell spacing and cell padding.

So a table with empty cells will take some space unless you reset the values as follows:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

By adding these attributes, the table will collapse to 0x0 dimensions.
(Based on using Firefox to inspect the `table` element.)

A more standards compliant approach is:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

which gives a similar effect but leaves a table with 2x4 dimensions, so there is a bit of residual space.

Finally, the surest CSS method for removing the space is

```
tr {
    display: none;
}
```

(Just remember to use `display: table-row` to reset the original display type.)

As of HTML5, `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` are obsolete but browsers may still respond to these attributes.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/MzzrV/